# rookie question about bootstrap installation and use

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, cdn

So i am trying to build this website and as i go on i decided to use a bootstrap carousel, i already had a dropdown button in the navbar and a collapse menu when on smaller viewports and it all worked fine, but when i was implementing the carousel it had a delay between images. It was almost like a white page between them and i wasnt sure if my website was simply slow or if it was a feature of the carousel but since the other features worked fine then i doubted it was the website speed problem, also it has almost no code whatsoever.
So i had a bunch of script codes for bootstrap css and js and i decided to delete them all and put simply the 2 that are on the official bootstrap website and since then not just the carousel problem persists (the huge delay between images with a blank white space) and also the other features stoped working. Can someone help me implement bootstrap correctly?

heres the full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <title>Name</title>
    
</head>


<body>
<!---------------------------------------------            NAVIGATION BAr --------------------------------------------------->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top ">
        <a class="navbar-brand " href="#">Name</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
      
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="/index.html">Home <span class="sr-only"></span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="/test.html"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-telephone-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M1.885.511a1.745 1.745 0 0 1 2.61.163L6.29 2.98c.329.423.445.974.315 1.494l-.547 2.19a.678.678 0 0 0 .178.643l2.457 2.457a.678.678 0 0 0 .644.178l2.189-.547a1.745 1.745 0 0 1 1.494.315l2.306 1.794c.829.645.905 1.87.163 2.611l-1.034 1.034c-.74.74-1.846 1.065-2.877.702a18.634 18.634 0 0 1-7.01-4.42 18.634 18.634 0 0 1-4.42-7.009c-.362-1.03-.037-2.137.703-2.877L1.885.511z"/>
              </svg></i> Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Services
              </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-calendar" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                  <path d="M3.5 0a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5V1h8V.5a.5.5 0 0 1 1 0V1h1a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v11a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H2a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V3a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h1V.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5zM1 4v10a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h12a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V4H1z"/>
                </svg>  Booking</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
              </div>
            </li>
           </ul>
           <span class="navbar-text">
            Name o slogan
          </span>
        </div>
      </nav>
<!---------------------------------------------            NAVIGATION BAr       --------------------------------------------------->


<!--------------------------------------------              HERO               ----------------------------------------------------->
<div class="p-5 text-center bg-image" style="
      height: 700px;
    ">
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center h-100">
        <div class="text-white">
          <h1 class="nomeEmpresa">Daniela Gonçalves Manicure</h1>
          <h4 class="mb-3">Frontignan</h4>
          <a class="btn btn-* btn-lg " href="#!" role="button">Prendez a rendevouz</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<!--------------------------------------------              HERO               ----------------------------------------------------->

<div class="separador"></div>

<!--------------------------------------------             Carroussel          ------------------------------------------------------->

<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active" style="background-color: aqua;">
      <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item" style="background-color: black;">
      <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item" style="background-color: rgb(250, 0, 0);">
      <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
  </button>
  <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
  </button>
</div>









<!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

i tried different versions cdn and it still does not work

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your link isn't the latest update available.
In your header, try this link instead :

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're just using the wrong version of bootstrap's css/js.

Change

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

to

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

so you're using bootstrap v5.0.2 (not css v4.6.2 and js v5.2.2).

Here is a working example.

```css
.slide img {
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Name</title>

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active" style="background-color: aqua;">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=a" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item" style="background-color: black;">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=b" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item" style="background-color: rgb(250, 0, 0);">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=c" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
      </button>
      <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
      </button>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add some description

Comment: Thanks for helping! With the new cdns the carousel is working wonders and the css is working fine too i think, but the dropdowns and collapse are still not working :C

Comment: Ok i think i was using old code too i guess, (from the tutorial video i think XD) i went to bootstrap website and changed the dropdown code and the collapse too and its all working fine now! thanks :D